# Rails Stub a variable inside module

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, mocha.js

I wrote a unit test for this module and want to stub `current_account` variable which comes from application controller.
(its global method written in application controller)

```
Module Foo
 def querying_result(criteria)
  User.find_by_account(current_account).where(criteria: criteria)
 end
end
```

I tried with following

```
Foo.stubs(current_account: @user.account).returns(@user.account)
Foo.any_instance.stub(current_account:@user.account).and_return(@user.account)
```

My Test file

```
class FooTest << ActiveSupport::TestCase
  context "querying the result"
    setup do
    @user = User.first
  end
  should "return all users" do
    users = querying_result(criteria)
    assert_equal users.count, 1
  end
end
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see `Foo` module might be included directly in the FooTest.

This is weird, but to make it work you should probably (only guessing) stub `self` not `Foo` (`self.stubs...`).

**But this is not how you supposed to test modules.**

IMO one should test classes that include this module. And if you don't want to tie your test to any specific class - create one inside the spec.

```
@dummy_class = Class.new do
   include Foo
   def initialize(current_account)
     @current_account = current_account # you can control this now by injecting the account on object creation
   end
   attr_accessor :current_account
end
```

and in test something like

```
@foo = @dummy_class.new(@user)
assert_equal(@foo.querying_result(criteria).count, 1)
```

You can also skip the `initialize` part and just stub `@foo` object.