# RSpec how to mock controller method inside concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, rspec-rails

I have the following:

```
class PaymentController < ActionController::API
  include ObjectActions

  def error_notification(message)
    puts "An error has occurred: #{message}"
  end
end

module ObjectActions
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def process
    if valid?
      # process payment
    else
      error_notification("Payment is not valid")
    end
  end
end
```

Now, I'm trying to mock/stub the "external" `error_notification` method inside `ObjectActions` module/concern.

```
RSpec.describe ObjectActions, type: :concern do
  include ObjectActions

  before do
    allow(described_class).to receive(:valid?).and_return(false)

    # I KNOW THIS IS NOT RIGHT, HOW CAN I PROPERLY MOCK IT?
    allow(described_class).to receive(:error_notification).and_return("Blah blah")
  end

  context '#process' do
    it { expect { process }.to eq("Blah blah") }
  end
end
```

Comment: So you know you're doing it completely wrong, and still want it to be done? What's the point?

Comment: What is this `type: :concern`? I've never seen it before, and don't see it in official rspec docs.

Comment: @nattfodd the logic is not wrong, i'm just trying to figure out the way to mock such case

Comment: @meta this way I "mark" my concern specs and apply some configs in rails_helper.rb

Comment: can you share this code (`rails_helper.rb`) as well?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer would be

```
allow(self).to receive(:error_notification).and_return("Blah blah")
```

Why?

You're including the module, you want to test in the current test

```
RSpec.describe ObjectActions, type: :concern do
  include ObjectActions
```

So this is what you're supposed to mock. But it's a bit better way to do it, which I described not long ago in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48914463/299774